# Getting the Max and min price range for a chart ADX using MQL5

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

I have tried the following:

```
adx_output = iADX(_Symbol,TimePeriod,Candles_for_adx);
Print(ChartGetDouble(0,CHART_PRICE_MAX,2));
Print(ChartGetDouble(0,CHART_PRICE_MIN,2));
Print(ChartGetDouble(0,CHART_POINTS_PER_BAR,2));
```

But the above code gives me the mid value for the current or tick based time series. I want to access the range for the previous candles. But could not find anything that can be helpful.
Please let me know the suggestion for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

### You do not check the right values

Well,
using MetaTrader's GUI Graph's attributes `{ CHART_PRICE_MIN, 
CHART_PRICE_MAX }` is possible, yet the Graph's layout is controlled by aPriceDOMAIN events ( QUOTE-s ) and some configurable options, yet not by the ADX Technical Indicator values per-se, so such retrieved numbers, received from GUI-state, have almost nothing to do with the actually sought for `{ min, MAX }`-ADX values.

### Approach:

- a smart yet complicated approach would be to create a CustomIndicator or a class, doing this exact service.
- a naive but functional approach would be to check and re-check the desired `iADX()-{ MAIN, +DI, -DI }` values:

---

```
/* -----------------------------------------------//
int  iADX(                                        // MQL5-call-inteface:
           string           symbol,               //      symbol name
           ENUM_TIMEFRAMES  period,               //      period
           int              adx_period            //      averaging period
           );
*/

#define currentChartID         0
#define currentChartMainWINDOW 0

int    nBARsVISIBLE = ChartGetInteger( currentChartID, CHART_VISIBLE_BARS,
                                       currentChartMainWINDOW
                                       ); 
double iADX_VISIBLE[nBARsVISIBLE];
double iADX_VISIBLE_min,
       iADX_VISIBLE_MAX;
int    iADX_IndicatorHANDLE = iADX( _Symbol,
                                     TimePeriod,
                                     Candles_for_adx
                                     );
/* -----------------------------------------------//
int  CopyBuffer(                                  // MQL5-call-inteface:
                  int       indicator_handle,     // indicator handle
                  int       buffer_num,           // indicator buffer number
                  int       start_pos,            // start position
                  int       count,                // amount to copy
                  double    buffer[]              // target array to copy
                  );
*/
int RetCODE = CopyBuffer( iADX_IndicatorHANDLE,
                          MODE_MAIN,              // { 0: MODE_MAIN | 1: MODE_PLUSDI | 2: MODE_MINUSDI }
                          0,
                          nBARsVISIBLE,
                          iADX_VISIBLE
                          );
 if ( RetCODE == -1 ) {...}
 else {
       iADX_VISIBLE_min = iADX_VISIBLE[ ArrayMinimum( iADX_VISIBLE ) ];
       iADX_VISIBLE_MAX = iADX_VISIBLE[ ArrayMaximum( iADX_VISIBLE ) ];
       ...
 }
```

---

Given the [**last** comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49574223/getting-the-max-and-min-price-range-for-a-chart-adx-using-mql5/49611303#comment86303261_49611303):

> Well, this might be the answer to my question but sir, I want the graph limits not the ADX min max. I can calculate it later, but currently want to have the graph limits. I am trying some experiments with the ADX graph. – [Jaffer Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4948889/jaffer-wilson) [1 hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49574223/getting-the-max-and-min-price-range-for-a-chart-adx-using-mql5/49611303#comment86303261_49611303)

```
   #define currentChartID          0       // adapt to fit your current setup
   #define currentChartSubWinID    0       // adapt to fit your current setup

   double priceMin = ChartGetDouble( currentChartID,
                                     CHART_PRICE_MIN,
                                     currentChartSubWinID
                                     );
   double priceMax = ChartGetDouble( currentChartID,
                                     CHART_PRICE_MAX,
                                     currentChartSubWinID
                                     );
   Print( "INF:: Chart(", currentChartID, ":", currentChartSubWinID, ").CHART_PRICE_MAX = ", priceMin );
   Print( "INF:: Chart(", currentChartID, ":", currentChartSubWinID, ").CHART_PRICE_MAX = ", priceMax );
```

Comment: Actually, I am trying to access the chart Y axis values the minimum and the maximum. I guess the above code is not doing that. Still I will check it.

Comment: Sorry, if misunderstood your question narrative. The chart sort of auto-formats itself. This code strived to find { min, MAX }-values of the ADX-indicator, that you have posted in the Question above. The indicator lines can easily run outside of the current graph limits, so checking the graphs-(min,MAX) does not reflect the ADX-{min,MAX}-values for the same visible period. Never mind.

Comment: Well, this might be the answer to my question but sir, I want the graph limits not the ADX min max. I can calculate it later, but currently want to have the graph limits. I am trying some experiments with the ADX graph.